# Dockerfile: Command works in Dockerfile but not in shell script

Tags: docker, shell, liquibase

I am running a liquibase command in my dockerfile and it executes successfully.

> CMD liquibase/liquibase/ --url=$My_URL --username $Username --password $Password --loglevel=$LogL --changeLogFile /changes/postgresql.xml update

However, if I execute this is a sh script.

> liquibase/liquibase/ --url=$My_URL --username $Username --password $Password --loglevel=$LogL --changeLogFile /changes/postgresql.xml update

Then I get this error:

> ' (options must start with a '--')e.integration.commandline.Main - Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unexpected value 'update
> ' (options must start with a '--')singException: Unexpected value 'update

I do not understand why this command executes as expected in the Dockerfile but only partially runs in the shell script. What I mean by partially is that the command does open the liquibase Jar file and displays the ASCII logo. But then I see the 'unexpected value update' error.

Any idea on how to correct the command in the shell script?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an [mcve], including details like the complete shell script and how you're launching the container?  Have you run a tool like ShellCheck to look for things like quoting errors in the script?

Comment: @CaptainKidd: Run the script with `-x` enabled, and post the **exact** error message you got. Also please use proper formatting in your question for the code, so that we, for instance, can see the spaces exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have excess / at the end of liquibase/liquibase/.
Also, make sure all variables used in the shell command are defined:

```
echo $My_URL
echo $Username
echo $Password
echo $LogL
```

If not, export them via

```
export Username=bob
export Password=caution_this_is_not_secure
export My_URL=...
...
```

Comment: While there is indeed an unneeded `/` at the end of the command, this should not matter. For instance, `/usr/bin/echo x` and `/usr/bin/echo/ x` both work the same.

Comment: No, this is not true, at least in Linux shell:

"user@chi:~$ /bin/echo/ x" will cause "-bash: /bin/echo/: Not a directory"

Comment: corrected the ending "/" and still no luck

Comment: Have you checked if the environment variables are set?

Comment: @ValeryPanov : Perhaps this depends on the bash version? I could confirm your findings with bash 3.2 on MacOS, but it works fine with bash under Cygwin, which is some 4.x (I don't have access to that computer right now, so I can't check the exact version).